# android bottom navigation with one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe

I'm creating a mobile app and in my bottom navigation I will have 4 
    icons.

I started off by using a different activity for each icon because on     one icon I will be adding a swipe bar on top and wasn't sure if I can do that with fragments.

I'm not sure if I'm saying this right but is it possible for me to 
just use one activity and a like seven different fragments to create this app. 
    One fragment for each icon but one icon will include the ability to swipe to 
    other fragments.

Is that possible?

Comment: Everything is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this by implementing VIEWPAGER in this. Here is reference for same.

You can do all this stuff without coding so much by using only **viewpager** with **tablayout**. Following will be the procedure:
Your main Layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout      android:id="@+id/tabDots"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"      app:tabGravity="center"
  app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Hook up your UI elements in activity or fragment as follows:
Java Code:

```
 mImageViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager); 
 TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDots);      tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mImageViewPager, true);
```

That's it your are good to go.

Now you can set your tabs in TabLayout. And manipulate your VIEWPAGER with this tabs.

Following xml resource file you will need to create in **drawable** folder..
**tab_indicator_selected.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <layer-list      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item> 
 <shape android:innerRadius="0dp"      android:shape="ring"      android:thickness="4dp"      android:useLevel="false">
  <solid      android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
  </shape>
  </item> 
 </layer-list>
```

**tab_indicator_default.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <item> <shape android:innerRadius="0dp" android:shape="ring" android:thickness="2dp" android:useLevel="false"> <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/> </shape> </item> </layer-list>
```

**tab_selector.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_selected" android:state_selected="true"/> <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_default"/> </selector>
```